# is using `v-on` considered as bad practice?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I often read that I should not use HTML's `onclick` attribute because it decrease code readability. Instead I should make **event listener** in my *script.js*. So what do you think about `v-on:click`? Is it also considered as bad practice and should I write event listeners instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You might be concerned that this whole event listening approach violates the good old rules about “separation of concerns”. Rest assured - since all Vue handler functions and expressions are strictly bound to the ViewModel that’s handling the current view, it won’t cause any maintenance difficulty. In fact, there are several benefits in using v-on:
>
> - It’s easier to locate the handler function implementations within your JS code by skimming the HTML template.
> - Since you don’t have to manually attach event listeners in JS, your ViewModel code can be pure logic and DOM-free. This makes it easier to test.
> - When a ViewModel is destroyed, all event listeners are automatically removed. You don’t need to worry about cleaning it up yourself.

Verbatim From: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Why-Listeners-in-HTML